# How to remove 'ns1' prefix with PyXB or JaXB?

Tags: python, xml, jaxb, xml-namespaces, pyxb

From this xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
           targetNamespace="http://foo.org/FooIsNotBar" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="Foo" type="xs:string"/> 
</xs:schema>
```

I want to use PyXB to get this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Foo xmlns="http://foo.org/FooIsNotBar">hello</Foo>
```

So I did this:

```
pyxbgen -m test -u test.xsd # Where test.xsd is the above xsd file
echo -e "import test\\nprint test.Foo('Hello World').toxml()" | python
```

Unfortunately I get an XML that has the unwanted `ns1` prefix:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ns1:Foo xmlns:ns1="http://foo.org/FooIsNotBar">Hello World</ns1:Foo>
```

I would like to get rid of these `ns1:` prefixes. How?

**EDIT**

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14579115/2612235) about jaxb gives me some hints about that but, I did not find the solution to my issue yet.

I discovered that I can set my prefix using `test.Namespace.setPrefix('foo')`. Unfortunately I cannot hide the prefix.

A dirty solution would be to do this:

```
import test
rmp = 'REMOVE_ME_PLEASE'
test.Namesapce.setPrefix(rmp)
print test.Foo('Hello World').toxml().replace(rmp + ':', '').replace(':' + rmp, '')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just remove the prefix because the XML wouldn't be valid anymore.  You can hide it by setting a default namespace as in [this example](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_usebind.html#influencing-element-and-mixed-content-order):

```
import pyxb.utils.domutils
pyxb.utils.domutils.BindingDOMSupport.SetDefaultNamespace(test.Namespace)
```